# RegisterRoutes and the MvcSiteMapProvider MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvcsitemapprovider

Is it prossible to parse all the nodes of my MVC.sitemap in the RegisterRoutes Method? When I try I only see the root node (home). There are no childs ... here's my sitemap.

```
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-3.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-3.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd"
        enableLocalization="true">

  <mvcSiteMapNode controller="Home" action="Index" resourceKey="home">
    <mvcSiteMapNode controller="Home" action="About" resourceKey="about"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode controller="Home" action="Contact" resourceKey="contact"/>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>

</mvcSiteMap>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. The MvcSiteMapProvider uses request caching, which is not available until after the application starts. Even if we got around that, HttpContext is not available in IIS integrated mode.

Besides, your sitemap should be based on your routes, not the other way around.